# HOG of depth and IR image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, kinect, infrared

I want to know what is the difference in calculating the Histogram of Oriented Gradient(HOG) of sequence of depth images and active IR images (intensity images) from Kinect v2? which one will show better gradient change of the sequence of images?

Comment: Can I ask you to specify how you're planning to calculate the HOG in the depth image? It could be problematic because you can have holes, etc.

Comment: @G.Führ: for the depth image, HOG can be extracted on foreground image as I know